# Room Database migration of an app released on play google

Tags: android, android-room

I have an app released on play google.
This app uses room database with `exportSchema = false`, `createFromAsset()`, and `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`.
Now, I want to add another entity and make it keep old database data upon app update through google play. so I changed `exportSchema = true` and implemented auto migration as following [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#automated). I made it worked in this order.

1. changed exportSchema value to true to generate 1.json for version1 schema on version of the app released on play google.
2. then implemented auto migration as following official doc.
3. after auto migration implemented, 2.json is generated for version2 schema.

so far so good. however, **I wonder if I can just bump up the version code and name for release branch then generate aab file to upload to google play. what I am worried about is app crash or any other side effect since the app on google play doesn't have any information about migration such as 1.json at least because exportSchema value was false at the time I uploaded to google play.**

Will it be okay to upload updated aab(like what I have done) to google play? or should I upload the aab with `exportSchema = true` with 1.json first and then upload aab with 2.json to prevent any concerns just in case.

I misspelled aab as abb so I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it be okay to upload updated abb(like what I have done) to google play?

The schema's are not implemented with the package. The exportSchema only affects the saving of the schema at compile time. Thus whether or not exportSchema is true or false is not reflected in the abb.

As long as the App has been fully tested and works, then there should be no issue.

So **Yes** it should be OK.